# Refactor to Higher order function in Scala?

Tags: scala

Learning Scala and trying to refactor following two functions to remove duplicate logic. Should I be creating a higher order function or something else to avoid duplicate code? Have a few more similar methods with such duplicate code with only difference in calling different Domain methods.

Little confused over refactoring. Using Scala version 2.10

```
def authenticate = Action(parse.json) { request =>
  val json = request.body
  val input = Json.fromJson[User](json)
  input.asOpt match {
    case Some(m: User) => Ok(Domain.authenticate(m)).as("application/json")
    case None => Ok("bad input")
  }
}

def addUser = Action(parse.json) { request =>
  val json = request.body
  val input = Json.fromJson[User](json)
  input.asOpt match {
    case Some(m: User) => Ok(Domain.addUser(m)).as("application/json")
    case None => Ok("bad input")
  }
}
```

Comment: A simple procedural decomposition (writing a private method to capture the common `match` portion of the two methods) will do fine.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can do something like( **Untested** ):

```
private def common[A](f:User=>A)(request:RequestHeader) = {
  val json = request.body
  val input = Json.fromJson[User](json)

  input.asOpt match {
    case Some(m: User) => Ok(f(m)).as("application/json")
    case None => Ok("bad input")
  }
}

def addUser = Action(parse.json) { common(Domain.adduser)(_) }

def authenticate = Action(parse.json) { common(Domain.authenticate)(_) }
```

Comment: This will not work out of the box. `f` should be `f: User => A` and request should be typed something else than `Any`. The idea is ok though.

Comment: I assumed that the request sub-classed something hence `Any`. If you have the type I can edit it to reflect that. The request may also be set up as `private def common[A, B](f:User=>A)(request:B) = ...` I think. But setting it up to ensure that it has a body is tricky for me.

Comment: Thanks. That refactoring did the trick and yes f: is f:User =>A

Comment: The `request` is in most cases typed as `RequestHeader`. The partially applied method works, but it's more common to mark it as 'implicit' and adjust the action to `Action(parse.json) { implicit request => common(Domain.authenticate) }`

Answer (score 0):

Im new to Scala too but I think we can do something like this. Please correct me if Im wrong.

You can do something like this

```
def foo(f:Int=>Int,x:Int):Int = {f(x)}
   foo(x=>x+x,3)
```

So similarly, you can pass the function you want to call into the common function.